# How to average daily data to create a weekly estimate in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

I need to get weekly averages of AOD for CA for 15 years. The filter.calenderRange does not have a "week" options. I have filtered the data to the day level but am unsure how to average for the week. Here is an example of my code for the year 2000 : `

```
         var filtAOD00=AOD.filterDate('2000-03-01','2000-12-31');
         var CA=US.filterMetadata('NAME_1','equals','California');


          //function to filter out images with missing data

         var imgColPerday = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
                  ee.List.sequence(1,366).map(function(day){
         var image = filtAOD00.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(day,day,'day_of_year'))
         .select('Optical_Depth_047').mean();
         image=image.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat());
         return image.set('day_of_year', day)// set the day
         // filter out empty images
         })).filter(ee.Filter.listContains('system:band_names', 'Optical_Depth_047'));

         // then apply sampleRegions
           var data =  ee.FeatureCollection(imgColPerday.map(function(image){

         // calculate data
          var AOD00Census = image.sampleRegions({   
          collection: CA,
          scale: 1000,
          }).map(function(feat){
          return feat.set('day_of_year',image.get('day_of_year'));
          });  

           return AOD00Census;
            })).flatten();


       var polyOut = data.select(['.*'],null,false);
       Export.table.toDrive(polyOut, 'AOD_CACensus1km_00');
```

`

Comment: Please provide a complete running script, with any used assets shared including code-editor link. It makes it a lot faster/easier to help you.

Comment: Here is the link to my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/da544e548dfb4700b59f159de1fa072e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating means for every day in your date range, you can create means for every 7 days, including a week worth of imagery for every iteration.

```
var CA = US.filterMetadata('NAME_1', 'equals', 'California');

var startDate = ee.Date('2000-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2001-01-01')
var dayOffsets = ee.List.sequence(
  0, 
  endDate.difference(startDate, 'days').subtract(1),
  7 // Single day every week
)
var weeklyMeans = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  dayOffsets.map(function(dayOffset) {
    var start = startDate.advance(dayOffset, 'days')
    var end = start.advance(1, 'week')
    var year = start.get('year')
    var dayOfYear = start.getRelative('day', 'year')
    return AOD
      .filterDate(start, end)
      .select('Optical_Depth_047')
      .mean()
      .set('year', year)
      .set('day_of_year', dayOfYear)
      .addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
  })  
).filter(
  // filter out empty images
  ee.Filter.listContains('system:band_names', 'Optical_Depth_047')
)

var data = weeklyMeans.map(function(image) {
  return image.sampleRegions({
    collection: CA,
    scale: 1000,
  }).map(function(feat) {
    return feat.copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
  })
}).flatten()

print('first feature', data.first())

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: data,
  description: 'AOD_CACensus1km_00',
   // Specify what to export, to get cleaner result
  selectors: [
    'year', 
    'day_of_year', 
    'latitude', 
    'longitude', 
    'HASC_1',
    'Optical_Depth_047'
  ]
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/89cc7abf31b378752ff599d1d9ca3059

Comment: This is great! Thank you!